# Firebase's GeoFire iOS Setting titles of MKAnnotation Callout via getting data from the firebase Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am using **Firebase Geofire** in **iOS** Using **Objective-C** which shows `MKAnnotation` from the Database the data base data looks like this

[This is The image for the database dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqnnv.png)

And then i load the annotations easily

here is the code for `ViewController` class

```
        #import "ViewController.h"
        #import "DetailViewController.h"
        #import "Geofire.h"

        @interface ViewController () 
        {
            CLLocationDegrees parkLat;
            CLLocationDegrees parkLong;
            NSString *keyy;
        }

        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dict;
        @property (nonatomic, strong) Pin *pinAnnotation;
        @end

        @implementation ViewController

        @synthesize dict;
        @synthesize title;
        @synthesize pinAnnotation;

         - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

             // Initializers

              FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

             self.dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

             _geo = [[GeoFire alloc] initWithFirebaseRef: [[[ref child:@"locations"] child:@"keyword"] child:@"teacher"]];

           keyy = @"Park";

             // Setting the title Variable
            [[FIRAuth auth] addAuthStateDidChangeListener:^(FIRAuth * _Nonnull auth, FIRUser * _Nullable user) {

                title = user.displayName;
            }];


             // Setting the Geo For your current
             [[FIRAuth auth] addAuthStateDidChangeListener:^(FIRAuth * _Nonnull auth, FIRUser * _Nullable user) {
                 [self.geo setLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: lat longitude:log] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.displayName] withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                      if (error){
                       NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                         } else {
                    }
                    }];
              }];

             // Setting The Dummy park location
             [self.geo setLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: parkLat longitude:parkLong] forKey: keyy];
        }

      - (void)loadPins{


    self.regionQuery = [self.geo queryWithRegion:region];

    // Observes the Coordinates return an array
   [_regionQuery observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyEntered withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {

        pinAnnotation = [[Pin alloc] init];
        [pinAnnotation setKey: key];
        [pinAnnotation setCoordinate:location.coordinate];
        [pinAnnotation setSubtitle:keyy];

        [pinAnnotation setName:@""];


       [self.mapView addAnnotation:pinAnnotation];
       // Setting the array if annotations
        self.annotations[key] = pinAnnotation;

        [self setData];

       FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
       [[[[ref child:@"locations"] child:@"keyword"] child:@"teacher"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

           NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);

           NSDictionary *dictionary = snapshot.value;
           for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
               NSDictionary *subDictionary = dictionary[key];
               NSString *titlee = subDictionary[@"title"];
               NSLog(@"%@",titlee);
               [pinAnnotation setTitle: titlee];
           }
       }];

    }];


}

        - (void)setData{

           // This sets the data i have made some changes in the geofire class so i can add params to the ref
             dict = _geo.valuee;

           [dict setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
            title = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
          }

         - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
              [super viewDidAppear:animated];

              // load pins as the view appears
            [self loadPins];
        }

        // Unwanted right now
        - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
        }

        - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

              if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){
                  return nil;
              }
// Normal Annotation Code
               MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];

                    [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]];
                    [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];

               return annotationView;
        }

        - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

  // Going to the Detail View
            DetailViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];
              NSString *aTitle = view.annotation.title;
              [detailVC setText:aTitle];

           [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
            [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
```

I load the annotations easil as you look in the for loop inside the `loadPins` method when i set the title it just shows `"Arfb Kashyap"` in all the annotation callouts which is just in the first one of the parameter in the database.. So what i want to do know is so for example their is an `MKAnnotation` at Coordinates (please look inside the dashboard Picture)

```
37.33233141
122.0312186
```

so the title should be `"Aryan Kashyap"`

But their is another annotation as well at

```
37.3317034
-122.0336955
```

So the title for that should be `"Arfb Kashyap"`

Thanks in advance!